# How to show image in SecondViewController when button is clicked in FirstViewController

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

After several attempts I do not succeed to understand were is the error and why the image doesn't appear... This is my code.

myProtocol.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>

-(UIImage *)transferImage;

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<myProtocol, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UIView *view;
} 

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender; 

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h" 
#import "SecondViewController.h" 
#import "myProtocol.h"

@interface ViewController () 
@end 

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VoodooVibeThumb@2x.png"]];
    [view addSubview:_imageView];
    NSLog(@"VoodooVibeThumb@2x.png");
}

-(UIImage *)transferImage
{
    NSLog(@"VoodooVibeThumb@2x.png"); 
    return _imageView.image;
} 

- (IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender 
{    
    SecondViewController *secClass = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [secClass setImageName:@"VoodooVibeThumb@2x.png"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secClass animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
} 

@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
#import "myProtocol.h" 
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController: UIViewController <myProtocol, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UIView *secondView;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;
    id <myProtocol> myDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *myImage;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *transferImage;
@property(nonatomic,assign) id delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString *imageName;

-(void)callTransfer;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "myProtocol.h" 

@interface SecondViewController ()
@end 

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize delegate, myImage, transferImage;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_imageName]];
UIImageView * myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_imageName]];
[secondView addSubview:myImage];
}

-(void)callTransfer
{
    myImage.image=[delegate performSelector:@selector(transferImage)];
    myImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"VoodooVibeThumb@2x.png"];
    NSLog(@"%@",myImage.image);
    NSLog(@"I am in call transfer");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Comment: You have formatting problems with your post, and some of the code is garbled. You also don't show the action that is triggered on the button click that is supposed to invoke the second view controller. That's the most important bit to tell us about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are not initializing the myImage subview before adding it in the viewDidLoad method of SecondViewController.

Try removing:

```
[secondView addSubview:myImage];
```

from viewDidLoad, and add the following to viewWillAppear:

```
UIImageView * myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_imageName]];
```

just before:

```
[secondView addSubview:myImage];
```

There may be a better way of doing this, but this might get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: UIImageView * myimage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_imageName]];

Compare l'errore Unused variable 'myimage'

Comment: I corrected the code in my answer to use myImage, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

[secondView addSubview:myImage];

Error: Local declaration of 'myImage' hidesistance variable.

[image]

Comment: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage[UIImage imageNamed:_imageName]];
    [secondView addSubview:myImage];
}

Comment: Hi Matthew, are you sure? There are several errors in your code…

Comment: Code is not tested, but you have accepted my answer. Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage[UIImage imageNamed:_imageName]];
    [secondView addSubview:myImage];
}
```

I presume you've got a variable in your interface (either in .h or .m) called myImage so when you then create the local instance of myImage (UIImageView *myImage), XCode is getting confused. As it was declared latest (no reference, sorry) it is using the local declaration, but it is aware that there is an instance variable using the same name that can't be accessed. You instead want to save straight to the instance variable by removing the `UIImageView *` from your method

Hope this makes sense!

Matt